# Screensaver is not kicking in after the five minutes that I set for it

Tags: display, screensaver

I have an XPS-13.  Using a mouse with a cable, so it is not a problem of wireless mouse feedback to computer.

Comment: What operating system? Have you checked for background apps or services that could prevent screensaver from starting?

Answer (score 0):

Could be that due to cable elasticity, your mouse moves slightly on your desk and prevents the screensaver from kicking in. Unplug the mouse entirely, set the screensaver on, say, 2 minutes, and wait. If it does come up, your wired mouse is the culprit, and it should be fed to the cat...